# How to return an image or print an image from a Byte Array?

Tags: java, image

i need to "print" an image from a byte array, i don't want to save it as file, i just want to transform the byte array to an image. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'print' in this context? Visually present the image on screen? Have it printed by a printer?

Comment: For being more specific i have to add the image in a PDF report, im using iReport (the image element is waiting for an image), i would like to return the image when i use the scriptlet

Comment: Did you search for a solution? Did you try something?

Comment: I was trying to use MemoryImageSource Class but i don't know how to use it yet.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));`